# Finding the row position of a value and using it for calculation in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that defines a range and finds the highest and lowest value of that range.

What I want to do is get those values, find the rows for each of them, see if the row of the high value is smaller then the row of the low value, then do a calculation.

**Problem 1** For some reason I keep getting an invalid qualifier error in the line the uses the row for the comparison.

**Problem 2** If the low value comes before the high, how can I find the highest value in the range that comes before the low?

The relevant part of the code is:

```
 Set MDDRange = Worksheets("TIME").Range(Col_Letter(lColumn) & 2, Col_Letter(lColumn) & LastRow) '.Value

        MDDHigh = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(MDDRange)
        MDDHighPos = Worksheets("TIME SERIES").Range(MDDRange).Find(MDDHigh, LookIn:=xlWhole)

        MDDLow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MDDRange)
        MDDLowPos = Worksheets("TIME").Range(MDDRange).Find(MDDLow, LookIn:=xlWhole)


'if to see if mddhigh comes before mddlow

        If MDDHighPos.Row + 1 < MDDLowPos.Row + 1 Then ' error is here

            MDD = (MDDLow - MDDHigh) / MDDHigh

            Worksheets("STATS").Cells(6, lColumn).Value = MDD

        Else
            'if my high value is not before my low, how to find the highest value before the low?
        End If
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

**Modified Part correcting both problems (this is from the accepted answer from SJR and modifications from R3uK):**

```
Set MDDRange = Worksheets("TIME").Range(Col_Letter(lColumn) & 2, Col_Letter(lColumn) & LastRow) '.Value

        MDDHigh = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MDDRange)
        Set MDDHighPos = MDDRange.Find(MDDHigh)

        MDDLow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(MDDRange)
        Set MDDLowPos = MDDRange.Find(MDDLow)

        a = MDDHighPos.Row
        b = MDDLowPos.Row

'if to see if mddhigh comes before mddlow

        If a < b Then

            MDD = ((MDDLow - MDDHigh) / MDDHigh)

            Worksheets("STATS").Cells(6, lColumn).Value = MDD

        Else
'this creates a new range from begin of old range to the lowest value, and finds the highest value in this range, then calculates the drawdown

            Set MDDRangeNew = Worksheets("TIME").Range(Col_Letter(lColumn) & 2, Col_Letter(lColumn) & b)

            MDDHighNew = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MDDRangeNew)

            MDD = ((MDDLow - MDDHighNew) / MDDHighNew)

            Worksheets("STATS").Cells(6, lColumn).Value = MDD

        End If
```

Comment: `Set MDDHighPos = ...` as you are assigning an object variable.

Comment: @SJR : You beat me to it! ;)

Comment: @R3uK - your time will come!

Comment: @DGMS89 - I'm just curious, why do you increase the rows in `MDDHighPos.Row + 1 < MDDLowPos.Row + 1`?

Comment: To find the low value after the high, define a new range start right after the high value until the last row and use `MDDLow` and `MDDLowPos` again! ;)

Comment: @SJR Thanks for the answer. Works perfectly now. Care to write it as an answer?

Comment: @Wujaszkun That was just for testing purposes. I was trying to see if there was any impact from the fact that my range starts in row 2. Apparently I couldn't find any.

Comment: @R3uK Thanks for the answer. I need to find the highest value before the lowest (drawdown calculation). Can I use the same procedure for that?

Comment: @DGMS89 : I don't see why not! ;)

Comment: @DGMS89 - thanks, will do. Hadn't spotted the second bit but if you define a range from the first cell in MDDRange to MDDLowPos, then find the max and then do the find on that max value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Am assuming your variable declarations are at the beginning...

```
Set MDDRange = Worksheets("TIME").Range(Col_Letter(lColumn) & 2, Col_Letter(lColumn) & LastRow) '.Value

        MDDHigh = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(MDDRange)
        Set MDDHighPos = Worksheets("TIME SERIES").Range(MDDRange).Find(MDDHigh, LookIn:=xlWhole)

        MDDLow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MDDRange)
        Set MDDLowPos = Worksheets("TIME").Range(MDDRange).Find(MDDLow, LookIn:=xlWhole)


'if to see if mddhigh comes before mddlow

        If MDDHighPos.Row + 1 < MDDLowPos.Row + 1 Then ' error is here

            MDD = (MDDLow - MDDHigh) / MDDHigh

            Worksheets("STATS").Cells(6, lColumn).Value = MDD

        Else
            'if my high value is not before my low, how to find the highest value before the low?

             Set MDDRange = Worksheets("TIME").Range(Col_Letter(lColumn) & "2", Col_Letter(lColumn) & MDDLowPos.Row - 1)
             'And here you go again! ;)

        End If
```

Comment: Hehe! Btw, you could have provided a base of answer to the 2nd problem mentioned! ;)

Comment: @R3uK - yes, I had missed that, but added a comment above.

Comment: I edited to add the definition of the new range to use to find the new min! ;)

Comment: @R3uK - not sure that's right as the OP wants to find the highest before the min where the max is after the min?

Comment: My bad, I indeed did the opposite!^^ Corrected it!

Comment: @R3uK - you happy not to post as an answer, I don't want to take credit for your answer.

Comment: @R3uK- you're a scholar and a gent.